# Position of highcharts map series

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have a highcharts map that displays an SVG map (See below) .The map container spans over the full width but I cannot find the highcharts option that allows me to control the place at which the map itself (series) start. The map is currently centered inside the map container, and I want it to be aligned to the left. The HTML code which is generated by highcharts indicates that the svg g element class is "highcharts-series-group" but I cannot change the positioning though css.

This is my highcharts code:

```
var chart = new Highcharts.Map({
        chart: {
            renderTo: 'map_container',
            backgroundColor:'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1)',


        },
        tooltip: {
            backgroundColor: 'white',
            borderColor: 'black',
            borderRadius: 10,
            borderWidth: 1,
            shadow: false,
            useHTML: true,
            color: '#6DC1BA',
            padding: 0,
            formatter: function() {
                return '<b>' +  this.point.name +'</b>';
            }

        },
        title: {
            text: ''
        },

        mapNavigation: {
            enabled: true,
            enableDoubleClickZoomTo: true,
            enableMouseWheelZoom: false
        },
        legend: {
            enabled: false
        },



        series:
            [
                {

                    name: 'Community',
                    cursor: 'pointer',
                    color: '#f2f2f2',
                    borderColor: 'black',
                    states: {
                        hover: {
                            color: '#e86e6b',

                        }
                    },
                    point: {
                        events: {
                            click: pointClick
                        }
                    },

                    "type": "map",
                    "data": [
                        {
                            "name": "Western Part of west",
                            "code": "Westside",
                            "brief": "West side",
                            "path": "M686,-309L680,-304L676,-298L673,-297L668,-296L663,-296L657,-297L648,-299L644,-300L640,-299L637,-296L638,-295L641,-293L641,-291L640,-285L636,-283L623,-271L617,-282L614,-287L607,-291L604,-284L602,-282L600,-278L598,-275L597,-271L591,-274L586,-271L572,-258L572,-253L573,-250L575,-247L579,-247L585,-246L585,-244L586,-237L587,-235L586,-232L585,-229L590,-226L596,-217L598,-215L600,-210L603,-208L604,-207L606,-205L610,-202L612,-200L609,-198L607,-198L606,-197L600,-197L593,-194L590,-190L583,-184L578,-183L570,-179L568,-178L567,-177L568,-173L566,-172L566,-171L571,-165L576,-163L576,-160L576,-156L578,-153L577,-147L579,-141L585,-141L590,-141L593,-141L596,-141L596,-135L594,-117L588,-108L587,-104L587,-101L585,-95L583,-87L584,-84L585,-82L593,-66L601,-44L603,-35L608,-35L610,-33L616,-32L618,-32L624,-33L629,-31L631,-31L633,-31L641,-26L649,-25L650,-21L653,-20L656,-19L657,-16L659,-13L656,-12L651,-13L644,-9L640,-7L651,8L651,9L646,13L644,18L645,22L645,25L654,35L653,36L641,33L631,28L632,27L625,17L621,17L619,19L614,24L611,25L609,24L607,24L603,22L600,18L598,15L595,12L591,10L590,9L589,6L582,-5L580,-12L579,-14L580,-18L580,-23L581,-35L583,-38L581,-40L563,-43L563,-35L561,-18L560,-15L562,-15L561,-14L563,-13L562,-9L562,-9L567,-8L565,-2L568,-2L572,4L577,8L576,11L576,10L574,11L569,10L569,10L570,9L569,9L569,8L565,7L564,8L563,8L563,7L563,6L563,6L562,5L556,3L549,18L550,18L548,22L547,21L539,26L533,24L533,24L539,14L533,8L524,0L515,18L514,19L506,29L500,38L482,21L481,19L483,10L482,4L474,-2L471,-3L462,-3L462,-5L465,-10L467,-12L463,-13L470,-19L469,-26L467,-25L462,-20L456,-17L453,-21L452,-22L449,-21L445,-23L442,-23L441,-17L441,-16L441,-12L438,-10L436,-9L427,-7L416,-20L415,-17L414,-4L414,-2L373,10L322,13L300,21L298,22L289,25L280,29L270,29L266,30L258,29L250,28L233,27L228,27L222,25L218,22L215,17L208,14L202,14L197,14L193,13L183,17L185,30L179,46L169,59L158,65L173,79L173,80L163,79L147,62L143,63L139,65L137,65L136,65L135,65L134,66L134,66L133,67L132,67L131,68L130,68L129,69L100,97L98,99L96,101L94,103L91,104L90,105L88,105L87,106L85,107L82,107L80,108L78,108L74,108L74,108L74,108L73,108L73,108L73,108L72,108L72,108L71,108L71,107L71,107L70,107L70,107L69,107L69,106L67,104L66,101L65,101L65,100L65,99L65,98L65,97L65,97L64,40L64,40L64,39L64,39L64,39L64,39L64,39L64,38L65,38L65,38L65,38L77,23L78,23L78,23L78,23L78,22L78,22L79,22L79,22L79,22L79,22L79,22L80,22L80,22L80,22L80,22L80,22L80,22L81,22L81,22L81,22L81,22L81,22L82,22L82,22L82,22L82,23L82,23L83,23L88,29L94,36L94,36L94,36L94,36L94,36L94,36L94,36L94,36L94,36L94,36L94,36L94,36L94,36L94,36L94,36L94,36L94,36L94,36L94,36L94,36L94,36L94,36L94,36L94,36L94,36L94,36L88,41L83,47L85,50L87,53L89,56L91,58L94,61L94,61L94,61L94,61L94,61L94,61L94,61L94,61L94,61L94,61L94,61L94,61L94,61L94,61L94,61L94,61L94,61L94,61L94,61L94,61L94,61L94,61L94,61L94,61L94,61L94,61L94,61L94,61L94,61L93,61L93,61L93,61L93,61L93,61L93,61L93,61L93,61L93,61L93,61L93,61L93,61L93,61L93,61L93,61L93,61L93,61L93,61L93,61L93,61L93,61L93,62L93,63L93,63L93,64L93,65L94,66L94,66L94,67L94,67L94,67L94,67L94,67L94,67L94,67L94,67L94,67L94,67L94,67L94,67L94,67L94,67L94,67L94,67L94,67L94,67L94,67L94,67L94,67L94,67L94,67L94,67L94,67L105,63L106,62L107,62L108,62L109,61L109,60L110,60L111,59L111,59L112,58L113,57L113,56L113,56L114,55L114,54L115,40L116,36L116,33L115,26L115,16L117,2L119,4L121,7L124,9L126,11L129,12L129,13L130,13L130,13L130,13L131,13L131,14L132,14L132,14L132,14L133,14L133,14L134,14L134,14L134,14L135,13L135,13L135,13L136,13L136,13L137,12L137,12L137,12L138,12L138,12L138,11L139,10L139,10L140,9L140,8L140,7L141,6L141,5L141,4L141,3L140,-7L140,-8L140,-8L140,-8L140,-8L140,-8L140,-9L140,-9L140,-9L140,-9L140,-9L140,-10L140,-10L140,-10L140,-10L140,-10L141,-11L141,-11L141,-11L141,-11L141,-11L141,-11L142,-11L142,-11L142,-11L142,-11L142,-11L143,-11L143,-11L143,-11L143,-11L143,-11L144,-11L144,-11L144,-11L144,-11L144,-11L145,-11L148,-10L151,-9L154,-8L154,-8L155,-8L155,-8L155,-8L156,-8L156,-8L157,-8L157,-9L157,-9L158,-9L158,-9L159,-9L159,-10L159,-10L160,-10L161,-11L161,-12L162,-13L162,-13L163,-14L163,-15L163,-16L164,-16L164,-17L164,-17L164,-17L164,-18L164,-18L164,-18L164,-19L164,-19L164,-20L164,-20L163,-20L163,-21L163,-21L161,-26L161,-26L161,-26L161,-26L161,-26L161,-26L161,-26L161,-26L161,-26L161,-26L161,-26L161,-26L161,-26L161,-26L161,-26L161,-26L161,-26L161,-26L161,-26L161,-26L161,-26L161,-26L161,-26L161,-26L161,-26L161,-26L161,-26L161,-26L161,-26L161,-26L161,-26L161,-26L161,-26L161,-26L161,-26L161,-26L161,-26L168,-27L168,-27L168,-27L169,-27L169,-27L169,-27L170,-27L170,-28L171,-28L171,-28L171,-28L173,-30L173,-30L173,-30L173,-30L173,-30L173,-30L173,-30L173,-30L173,-30L173,-30L173,-30L173,-30L173,-30L173,-30L174,-30L174,-30L175,-30L176,-30L176,-30L177,-31L177,-31L178,-31L178,-31L179,-31L179,-32L179,-32L180,-33L181,-34L181,-35L182,-36L182,-37L182,-38L183,-39L183,-40L183,-41L183,-42L183,-43L183,-44L183,-45L183,-45L183,-45L183,-45L183,-45L183,-45L183,-45L183,-45L183,-45L183,-45L183,-45L183,-45L183,-45L183,-45L183,-45L183,-45L182,-46L181,-47L180,-48L179,-49L178,-50L177,-51L176,-52L171,-60L168,-60L168,-60L168,-60L168,-60L168,-60L168,-60L168,-60L168,-60L168,-60L168,-60L168,-60L168,-60L168,-60L168,-60L168,-60L168,-60L168,-60L165,-64L165,-64L165,-64L164,-64L164,-64L164,-65L164,-65L164,-65L163,-65L163,-65L162,-65L162,-66L162,-66L161,-66L161,-66L161,-66L160,-66L160,-66L159,-66L159,-66L159,-66L158,-66L155,-79L157,-81L157,-81L157,-81L157,-81L157,-81L157,-81L157,-81L157,-81L157,-81L157,-81L157,-81L157,-81L157,-81L157,-81L157,-81L157,-81L156,-83L156,-83L156,-83L156,-83L156,-84L156,-84L156,-84L156,-84L156,-84L156,-85L156,-85L156,-85L156,-85L156,-85L156,-86L157,-86L157,-86L157,-86L157,-86L157,-86L158,-87L158,-87L158,-87L158,-87L160,-88L162,-89L164,-90L167,-90L169,-91L169,-92L169,-92L167,-94L166,-94L166,-95L165,-95L165,-95L165,-95L164,-95L164,-96L163,-96L162,-96L162,-96L161,-96L161,-96L160,-96L160,-96L159,-96L157,-96L155,-96L153,-96L151,-95L148,-95L146,-94L146,-93L146,-91L146,-90L146,-89L145,-88L145,-87L145,-85L118,-80L115,-85L115,-85L115,-86L115,-86L115,-86L115,-86L115,-86L115,-87L115,-87L115,-87L114,-87L114,-87L114,-87L114,-87L114,-87L113,-87L113,-87L113,-87L113,-87L113,-87L112,-87L112,-87L112,-87L112,-87L112,-87L112,-87L108,-86L107,-86L107,-86L107,-86L107,-86L107,-85L106,-85L106,-85L106,-85L106,-85L105,-84L105,-84L105,-84L104,-84L104,-84L83,-82L82,-82L82,-82L82,-82L82,-82L82,-82L81,-82L81,-82L81,-82L81,-82L81,-82L80,-82L80,-83L80,-83L80,-83L80,-83L79,-83L79,-84L79,-84L79,-84L79,-84L79,-84L79,-84L79,-85L79,-88L79,-89L79,-89L79,-89L79,-89L79,-89L79,-90L79,-90L79,-91L79,-92L79,-93L79,-94L79,-95L79,-97L79,-98L79,-99L78,-100L78,-101L78,-103L78,-104L78,-105L78,-106L78,-106L78,-106L78,-107L78,-107L78,-108L78,-108L78,-108L79,-109L79,-109L79,-109L79,-109L79,-110L79,-110L80,-110L80,-110L81,-110L81,-111L81,-111L82,-111L83,-111L84,-111L85,-111L86,-112L87,-112L88,-112L87,-132L84,-134L83,-134L83,-134L83,-134L83,-134L83,-134L82,-135L82,-135L82,-135L82,-135L82,-135L81,-136L81,-136L81,-136L81,-136L81,-136L81,-137L79,-146L78,-147L78,-147L78,-148L77,-149L77,-150L77,-150L76,-151L75,-151L75,-152L74,-152L74,-153L73,-153L72,-154L71,-154L62,-158L62,-158L61,-158L61,-158L61,-159L60,-159L60,-159L59,-159L59,-160L59,-160L58,-160L58,-161L58,-161L58,-162L58,-162L57,-162L57,-163L57,-163L57,-164L57,-164L57,-164L57,-165L57,-165L56,-165L56,-166L56,-166L56,-167L53,-167L52,-166L51,-166L51,-166L50,-165L49,-165L49,-165L48,-165L47,-165L47,-165L46,-164L45,-164L45,-164L36,-160L33,-159L31,-157L31,-156L30,-156L30,-155L29,-154L29,-154L29,-153L28,-153L28,-153L28,-153L28,-153L28,-152L27,-152L27,-152L27,-152L27,-152L27,-152L26,-152L26,-152L26,-152L26,-152L26,-152L25,-152L25,-152L25,-152L25,-153L25,-153L25,-153L24,-153L16,-153L11,-153L8,-153L8,-153L8,-153L8,-153L8,-153L8,-153L8,-153L8,-153L8,-153L8,-153L8,-153L8,-153L8,-153L8,-153L8,-153L8,-153L8,-153L8,-153L8,-153L8,-153L8,-153L4,-157L4,-158L4,-159L3,-159L3,-160L3,-160L3,-161L2,-161L2,-162L2,-163L2,-164L2,-164L3,-171L3,-172L3,-173L3,-174L4,-175L4,-176L5,-177L7,-180L8,-181L9,-182L11,-182L12,-183L13,-183L15,-184L15,-184L16,-184L16,-184L17,-184L17,-185L17,-185L19,-186L20,-187L20,-187L21,-188L21,-188L21,-188L22,-188L22,-188L23,-188L23,-189L23,-189L24,-189L24,-189L27,-190L28,-190L31,-191L31,-191L31,-191L31,-191L32,-191L32,-191L32,-191L32,-191L32,-191L33,-191L33,-191L33,-191L33,-191L33,-191L33,-191L33,-191L33,-191L33,-191L33,-191L33,-191L33,-191L33,-191L33,-191L33,-191L33,-191L33,-191L33,-191L33,-191L33,-191L33,-191L33,-191L33,-191L33,-192L33,-192L33,-192L33,-192L33,-192L33,-192L33,-193L33,-193L33,-193L34,-193L34,-195L27,-207L26,-228L27,-247L46,-255L52,-257L58,-257L60,-257L63,-256L65,-255L66,-254L66,-253L66,-253L66,-253L66,-253L66,-252L66,-252L64,-251L63,-250L62,-248L59,-245L58,-244L57,-243L56,-241L58,-236L71,-210L71,-203L71,-202L72,-201L72,-200L72,-200L72,-199L72,-198L73,-197L73,-197L74,-196L74,-196L75,-195L75,-195L76,-194L77,-193L78,-192L80,-192L80,-191L81,-191L82,-191L83,-191L84,-191L84,-190L85,-190L86,-190L87,-190L87,-190L88,-191L88,-191L89,-191L89,-191L89,-191L89,-191L89,-191L90,-191L90,-192L90,-192L90,-192L90,-192L91,-192L91,-193L91,-193L91,-193L91,-193L91,-193L92,-194L92,-195L92,-195L92,-196L92,-196L92,-197L92,-197L92,-198L92,-198L92,-198L92,-199L92,-199L92,-199L92,-199L92,-199L92,-200L92,-200L92,-200L93,-200L93,-200L93,-201L93,-201L93,-201L94,-201L94,-201L94,-201L94,-202L120,-212L120,-212L121,-213L121,-213L122,-213L122,-213L122,-214L123,-214L123,-214L124,-215L124,-215L124,-215L124,-216L124,-216L125,-217L125,-217L125,-217L125,-218L125,-218L125,-219L125,-219L125,-219L125,-219L125,-219L125,-220L125,-220L126,-220L126,-220L126,-220L126,-221L126,-221L126,-221L127,-221L127,-221L127,-221L127,-222L127,-222L128,-222L128,-222L128,-222L128,-222L128,-222L129,-222L129,-222L129,-222L146,-224L147,-223L149,-222L150,-221L151,-219L153,-209L153,-201L153,-199L151,-197L146,-194L143,-192L140,-191L132,-191L119,-190L110,-185L102,-180L100,-179L100,-177L101,-172L101,-147L110,-142L139,-149L160,-157L183,-161L207,-162L225,-167L229,-168L250,-160L303,-170L306,-172L305,-176L301,-181L291,-182L281,-183L272,-183L258,-194L259,-214L243,-226L239,-240L215,-252L214,-253L213,-254L212,-254L211,-255L211,-255L210,-256L205,-262L207,-265L207,-265L207,-266L208,-266L209,-266L218,-271L231,-279L237,-283L241,-287L243,-290L245,-293L248,-296L249,-299L250,-299L250,-300L250,-300L250,-301L250,-301L250,-301L250,-302L250,-302L250,-303L250,-303L250,-303L250,-304L250,-304L250,-304L250,-305L249,-305L249,-305L249,-305L249,-306L247,-308L245,-310L242,-312L242,-312L242,-312L242,-313L242,-313L242,-313L242,-313L242,-313L242,-314L242,-315L242,-315L242,-315L242,-315L242,-315L242,-315L242,-315L242,-315L242,-315L242,-315L242,-315L242,-315L242,-315L242,-315L242,-315L242,-315L242,-315L242,-315L242,-315L242,-315L242,-315L242,-315L242,-315L242,-315L242,-315L242,-315L242,-315L242,-315L242,-315L242,-315L242,-315L242,-315L242,-315L243,-314L244,-314L245,-314L246,-313L247,-313L248,-313L248,-312L248,-312L249,-312L250,-312L250,-312L251,-312L251,-312L252,-312L253,-312L253,-312L254,-312L254,-312L255,-312L255,-312L256,-313L256,-313L257,-314L258,-315L259,-316L260,-317L261,-318L264,-325L264,-325L264,-325L264,-325L264,-326L264,-326L264,-326L264,-326L264,-326L264,-327L264,-327L264,-327L264,-327L264,-327L264,-328L264,-328L263,-328L263,-328L263,-328L263,-329L263,-329L262,-329L260,-331L258,-333L256,-335L254,-337L252,-339L250,-341L249,-343L271,-343L288,-341L322,-347L333,-348L351,-351L351,-351L351,-352L351,-353L351,-354L350,-355L350,-355L350,-356L349,-357L349,-358L348,-358L348,-358L348,-358L348,-358L348,-359L347,-359L347,-359L347,-359L347,-359L347,-360L347,-360L347,-360L347,-360L347,-360L347,-361L347,-361L348,-362L348,-362L348,-363L348,-363L348,-363L348,-364L348,-364L347,-364L347,-365L347,-365L347,-365L344,-369L344,-369L344,-369L344,-369L344,-369L344,-370L344,-370L343,-370L343,-370L343,-370L343,-370L343,-370L343,-370L342,-370L342,-370L342,-370L342,-370L342,-370L341,-371L341,-371L341,-371L341,-371L341,-371L340,-372L340,-372L340,-372L340,-372L340,-372L339,-373L339,-373L339,-374L339,-374L339,-374L339,-374L339,-374L339,-374L339,-374L339,-374L338,-374L338,-374L338,-374L338,-374L338,-374L337,-374L337,-374L337,-375L336,-375L336,-375L336,-375L335,-375L335,-376L334,-376L334,-376L334,-377L334,-377L334,-377L333,-377L333,-377L333,-377L333,-378L333,-378L333,-378L333,-378L333,-378L333,-379L333,-379L333,-379L333,-379L333,-379L333,-380L333,-380L333,-380L333,-380L333,-380L333,-381L333,-381L333,-381L333,-381L333,-381L333,-382L333,-382L333,-382L333,-384L333,-384L333,-384L333,-384L333,-384L333,-384L333,-384L333,-384L333,-384L333,-384L333,-384L333,-384L333,-384L333,-384L333,-384L333,-384L333,-384L333,-384L333,-384L333,-384L333,-384L333,-384L333,-384L333,-384L333,-384L333,-384L333,-384L333,-384L332,-385L332,-385L332,-385L332,-385L332,-385L332,-386L332,-386L332,-386L332,-386L332,-386L332,-387L332,-387L332,-387L332,-387L332,-387L332,-388L332,-388L332,-388L332,-388L328,-397L328,-397L327,-398L327,-399L327,-400L326,-400L325,-401L320,-406L320,-406L320,-407L319,-407L319,-407L319,-407L319,-407L319,-408L319,-408L319,-408L318,-409L318,-409L318,-409L318,-409L318,-409L318,-410L318,-410L318,-410L318,-410L318,-410L318,-410L318,-411L318,-411L318,-411L319,-411L319,-411L319,-412L319,-412L319,-412L320,-412L320,-412L320,-413L320,-413L320,-413L321,-413L321,-413L321,-414L321,-414L321,-414L321,-414L321,-414L321,-415L321,-415L321,-415L321,-415L321,-415L321,-416L321,-416L321,-416L321,-416L321,-416L321,-416L321,-416L321,-416L321,-416L321,-416L321,-416L321,-416L321,-416L321,-416L321,-416L321,-416L321,-416L321,-416L321,-416L321,-416L321,-416L321,-416L321,-416L321,-416L321,-416L321,-416L321,-417L321,-417L321,-417L321,-417L321,-417L321,-417L321,-418L321,-418L321,-418L321,-419L321,-420L321,-421L321,-422L321,-423L322,-423L322,-424L322,-425L322,-426L322,-426L322,-427L322,-427L322,-427L322,-427L322,-427L322,-428L322,-428L322,-428L322,-428L322,-428L322,-429L322,-429L322,-429L322,-429L323,-429L323,-430L325,-432L330,-438L330,-438L330,-438L330,-438L331,-438L331,-438L331,-438L331,-438L331,-438L332,-438L332,-438L332,-438L332,-438L332,-438L333,-438L333,-438L333,-438L338,-438L343,-439L348,-440L353,-441L353,-441L353,-441L353,-441L353,-441L354,-441L354,-442L354,-442L354,-442L354,-442L355,-442L355,-443L355,-443L391,-443L419,-436L420,-435L420,-435L421,-434L422,-434L428,-431L429,-430L430,-430L432,-429L433,-429L434,-428L435,-427L438,-425L438,-424L439,-424L439,-424L439,-424L440,-424L440,-423L441,-423L441,-423L441,-423L442,-423L442,-423L443,-423L444,-423L444,-423L445,-423L445,-423L448,-423L450,-423L452,-423L455,-423L455,-423L455,-423L456,-423L456,-423L457,-423L458,-423L458,-423L459,-423L459,-423L459,-423L460,-423L460,-422L460,-422L461,-422L461,-422L462,-422L462,-421L462,-421L463,-421L463,-420L463,-420L464,-419L464,-419L464,-419L464,-418L464,-418L465,-418L465,-417L465,-417L465,-417L465,-416L465,-416L465,-416L465,-415L465,-415L465,-414L465,-414L465,-414L464,-413L463,-410L463,-409L463,-409L463,-409L463,-408L463,-408L463,-407L463,-407L464,-407L464,-406L464,-406L464,-406L464,-406L464,-406L464,-405L464,-405L464,-405L464,-405L464,-405L465,-405L465,-405L465,-405L465,-405L465,-405L465,-405L466,-405L466,-405L466,-405L466,-405L466,-405L467,-405L467,-405L467,-405L467,-405L467,-405L468,-405L468,-405L468,-405L468,-405L468,-405L469,-405L469,-405L469,-405L469,-405L469,-405L470,-405L470,-405L470,-405L470,-405L470,-405L471,-405L471,-405L471,-405L471,-405L471,-405L471,-405L472,-405L472,-405L472,-406L472,-406L472,-406L472,-406L473,-406L473,-406L473,-406L473,-406L473,-406L474,-406L474,-406L474,-406L474,-406L474,-406L475,-406L475,-406L475,-406L475,-406L475,-405L476,-405L476,-405L477,-405L477,-405L477,-404L477,-404L477,-404L478,-404L478,-404L478,-403L478,-403L478,-403L478,-403L479,-403L479,-402L479,-402L479,-402L479,-401L479,-400L479,-400L479,-399L479,-399L478,-398L478,-398L478,-397L478,-397L478,-397L478,-396L478,-396L478,-395L477,-395L477,-395L477,-394L477,-394L476,-394L476,-394L475,-393L475,-393L475,-393L475,-392L475,-392L475,-392L475,-391L475,-391L475,-390L476,-388L476,-388L476,-388L476,-388L476,-388L476,-388L476,-388L476,-388L476,-388L476,-388L476,-388L476,-388L476,-388L476,-388L476,-388L476,-388L476,-388L476,-388L476,-388L476,-388L476,-388L476,-388L476,-388L476,-388L476,-388L476,-388L476,-388L476,-388L477,-388L478,-388L479,-388L480,-388L481,-389L482,-389L482,-390L489,-391L495,-393L496,-393L496,-393L496,-393L497,-393L497,-393L501,-395L502,-395L502,-395L502,-395L503,-395L503,-395L504,-395L504,-395L504,-396L505,-396L505,-396L505,-396L505,-396L505,-397L505,-397L506,-397L506,-397L506,-397L506,-397L506,-398L506,-398L506,-398L506,-398L506,-398L507,-399L507,-399L507,-399L507,-399L507,-399L508,-400L508,-400L508,-400L508,-400L508,-401L508,-401L508,-401L508,-402L508,-402L508,-403L508,-403L508,-403L508,-403L509,-403L509,-403L509,-404L509,-404L509,-404L510,-404L510,-404L510,-405L510,-405L510,-405L511,-405L511,-405L511,-406L511,-406L511,-406L511,-406L512,-406L512,-407L512,-407L512,-407L512,-407L512,-407L512,-408L512,-408L512,-408L512,-408L512,-408L512,-409L512,-409L511,-409L511,-409L511,-409L508,-414L508,-414L508,-414L507,-415L507,-415L507,-416L507,-416L507,-416L507,-417L507,-417L507,-417L507,-418L507,-418L508,-419L508,-419L508,-419L508,-419L511,-413L514,-409L517,-400L548,-401L559,-397L576,-400L581,-399L580,-394L580,-392L581,-387L582,-381L582,-378L583,-375L585,-372L588,-370L592,-368L593,-367L596,-364L599,-359L604,-353L609,-348L609,-346L611,-339L612,-333L615,-323L618,-327L621,-330L623,-331L625,-332L626,-333L632,-332L639,-333L650,-333L659,-334L662,-331L667,-328L672,-323L679,-316L686,-309"
                        },


                },
            ]
    });
```

[image: Map Screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't be easier to set width for your chart? Probably 400px will be enough, see [`chart.width`](http://api.highcharts.com/highmaps#chart.width) option.

Another solution is to set fixed [`spacingRight`](http://api.highcharts.com/highmaps#chart.spacingRight), see [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/977LdLh4/).

Or [`marginRight`](http://api.highcharts.com/highmaps#chart.marginRight). Another [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/kpu4Ln1u/).

```
        chart: {
            borderWidth: 2,
            spacingRight: 400, //or marginRight
            plotBackgroundColor: '#E0E0E0'
        },
```